# Does "Joey Kangaroo" have a supplementary meaning?

Tags: idioms

My twins love Peppa Pig, and whenever it is possible I let them see the original English version. There's a rule of thumb that all "young" characters, except the piglets themselves, have a name which starts with the same letter as the name of the animal, from Suzy Sheep to Zoë Zebra). The one and only exception is the little brother of Kylie Kangaroo, whose name is... Joey.

A search with Google returns more that 30K results, so I was wondering if for an English-speaker (probably a British English speaker, or maybe an Australian English speaker) "Joey Kangaroo" means something specific. Does anybody know if this is the case?

Comment: *Joey* was 19th-century Australian slang, of uncertain origin, for a baby kangaroo, and has become the formal designation for the young of all marsupials.

Comment: I think [**joey** - Australian. A young animal, especially a baby kangaroo](http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=chr-greentree_gc&ei=utf-8&ilc=12&type=714647&p=define+joey) is General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, as far as the OP knows "Joey" is just a name. I wouldn't think to look for the *definition* of a name. I'd have [googled "Joey Kangaroo"](http://tinyurl.com/kjmlcwq) to see if the combination had any special meaning, as the OP thought. The wiki link that returns does have the answer, but you have to read a good chunk of the article to get there, (and I wouldn't expect to find the answer there, as the OP). Interestingly enough, I was going to make a point that you wouldn't [search "define kylie"](http://tinyurl.com/koxt8gn) and learned it's Australian slang for a boomerang!

Comment: @WendiKidd: Well, I just typed in [define joey](http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=chr-greentree_gc&ei=utf-8&ilc=12&type=714647&p=define+joey), and 4 of the first 6 matches give the relevant information without needing to actually follow up the links. Obviously OP *wasn't* aware of it, or he wouldn't be asking here. But I still think it's sufficiently well-known and easily-established that it's not a suitable question for ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it did not occur to me to search just for Joey, and I never came across that word - for me it was just a name.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know you did; I'm saying it never would have occurred to me to search "define [x]" for something I thought was only a name. So I think this is actually an interesting question. But we can definitely agree to disagree :)

Comment: @ mau: You don't say exactly what search term or search engine you used, but [using Yahoo, 6 of the first 8 results for **"joey kangaroo"**](http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?fr=chr-greentree_gc&ei=utf-8&ilc=12&type=714647&p=joey+kangaroo) would give the definition without needing to follow any links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *joey* is the terminology for a young Kangaroo. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/joey?q=joey and the last sentence of the **Terminology** section here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo

In addition to that, it is also used as a first name, for men and women. You can see that here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey and here http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/1/Joey